# Regular ideals are invertible

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $I$ be a fractional ideal of the ring $A$. Now $I$ is called *regular* if $I$ contains a regular element.

> Are regular ideals invertible?

A fractional ideal $I$ is called invertible if $II^{-1} = A$ where $I^{-1} = \{r \in \operatorname{Frac}(A) \mid rI \subseteq A\}$. Now since there is some regular $a\in I$, we know that $a^{-1}\in \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ and thus $1 = aa^{-1} \in II^{-1}$ which implies  $II^{-1} = A$ and thus the invertibility of $I$.

Does my proof contain any mistake or is this just simply true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is not true, as there are non-invertible ideals in domains (see [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535169/example-of-a-non-invertible-fractional-ideal)). The error in your proof would be to assume that if $a\in I$ then $a^{-1}\in I^{-1}$. For example, take $A=k[x,y]$ and $I=(x,y)$, as in the link. Then $x\in (x,y)$ but $x^{-1}$ is not an element of $I^{-1}$ because $x^{-1}y\not\in  A$ which means that $x^{-1}I\not\subset A$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not recognize that the elements of $I^{-1}$ need to wedge every element of $I$ into the ground ring.